# Nodejs, Serverless expected stub function to be called once but was called 0 times

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, sinon, serverless-framework

I have been the said error when trying to create a stub from sinon in my test function. I am trying to test a function responsible to make http calls to other endpoints. I am trying to understand why Its not resolving to the output provided.

```
const sinon = require('sinon');
const sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();

  describe('test endpoint', () => {
    it('should be test function', async () => {
      const stub = sinon.stub(someServiceMock.POST, '/funcName').resolves({ status: 204 });
      sinon.assert.calledOnce(stub);
    });
  });
});
```

and getting `AssertError: expected '/funcName' to be called once but was called 0 times`

The object i pass in the stub is

```
const someServiceMock = {
  POST: {
    '/funcName': () => {},
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The stubbed function is never called in the code-sample you provided. If you actually call the funtion with

```
describe('test endpoint', () => {
  it('should be test function', async () => {
    const stub = sinon.stub(someServiceMock.POST, '/funcName').resolves({ status: 204 });
    someServiceMock.POST["/funcName"]();
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(stub);
  });
});
```

the test should pass as expected.